# PHP Mail shows SMTP Error

Tags: email, php

I have tried many mailing scripts in php,But my server always shows SMTP error.I am using PHP5.Any please help..

Comment: Do you really have SMTP server? set USE SMPT = FALSE

Comment: Paste the exact errors .. there are so many SMTP errors :D

Comment: provide your SMTP connection code.

Comment: Show us the code or it didn't happen. Also specify your OS and Webserver, since mailing is handled quite differently on *nix and Windows...

Comment: actual error message + actual code = maybe get an answer. Anything else is pointless.

Comment: This question is a candidate for closure because it is of low quality.  You have to show work, some code samples, error messages.  Otherwise we are only guessing at your problems.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying your code on local machine, try upload it to someserver than try ...